# Send route param to middleware as argument Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes, middleware, laravel-5.1

Can I sent to middleware parameter from router as argument?

For simple:

```
Route::get('test/{param}',['middleware'=>['testing:{param}'],'uses'=>'TestController@method']);
```

Is there in Laravel isset method like this? I know about `Route::current()->parameters()` but I want to find better method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ask Laravel's team on GitHub about it. They answered that now any method like this not exists. They answer that I should use `$request->route()`.

Enjoy!