# Laravel use route parameter in middleware

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-middleware

Couldn't find anything that specifically matches my situation.  I have a route group defined as:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api/v1/{access_token}'], function(){
    ...
}
```

The above group has several resource routes inside.  I am trying to create a custom middleware that will validate the `access_token` parameter and return a 400 response if the parameter is not valid.  I would like to be able to so something like this in my controllers:

```
class ProductController extends Controller {

    /**
     * Instantiate a new ProductController
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('verifyAccessToken');
    }
    ...
}
```

My question is not "how do I define custom middleware", but rather, how can I gain access to the `access_token` parameter from **within** the `handle` function of my custom middleware?

EDIT:  While the question suggested as a duplicate is similar and has an answer, that answer seems to be outdated and/or unsatisfactory for what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you don't want to put the middleware on the route group its self?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Nope.  I usually prefer to define it in my controller, but I would be open to any solution that allows me to accomplish what I want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send route param to middleware as argument Laravel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32082758/send-route-param-to-middleware-as-argument-laravel)

Comment: Have you tried my answer? It should be exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just access it from your `$request` object using the magic `__get` method like this:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $token = $request->access_token;
    // Do something with $token
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware#middleware-parameters

For simple

```
public function yourmethod($access_token){
    $this->middleware('verifyAccessToken', $access_token);
}
```

I think you can't do it in `__construct()` method.

Comment: The point is to not have to duplicate the same code within every controller function...

Comment: @Vince try my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32082758/send-route-param-to-middleware-as-argument-laravel

Answer (score 0):

Just stick the middleware on the Route::group

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api/v1/{access_token}', 'middleware' => 'verifyAccessToken'], function(){

});
```

Then in your middleware, as Thomas Kim pointed out, you can use the `$request` object to gain access to the token that was passed to the route.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $token = $request->access_token;
    // Do something with $token
}
```